# Can XPath return only nodes that have a child of X?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is it possible to use XPath to select only the nodes that have a particular child elements?  For example, from this XML I only want the elements in pets that have a child of 'bar'.  So the resulting dataset would contain the `lizard` and `pig` elements from this example:

```
<pets>
  <cat>
    <foo>don't care about this</foo>
  </cat>
  <dog>
   <foo>not this one either</foo>
  </dog>
  <lizard>
   <bar>lizard should be returned, because it has a child of bar</bar>
  </lizard>
  <pig>
   <bar>return pig, too</bar>
  </pig>
</pets>
```

This Xpath gives me all pets: `"/pets/*"`, but I only want the pets that have a child node of name `'bar'`.

Comment: Don't underestimate the w3c specs in terms of readability and usefulness. It is probably faster to look the answers to questions like these in <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath">the spec</a>, which is very readable and complete, with many examples.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here it is, in all its glory

```
/pets/*[bar]
```

English: Give me all children of `pets` that have a child `bar`

Answer (score 28):

```
/pets/child::*[child::bar]
```

My pardon, I did not see the comments to the previous reply.

But in this case I'd rather prefer using the `descendant::` axis, which includes all elements down from specified:

```
/pets[descendant::bar]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case you wanted to be more specific about the children - you can also use selectors on them.

Example:

```
<pets>
    <cat>
        <foo>don't care about this</foo>
    </cat>
    <dog>
        <foo>not this one either</foo>
    </dog>
    <lizard>
        <bar att="baz">lizard should be returned, because it has a child of bar</bar>
    </lizard>
    <pig>
        <bar>don't return pig - it has no att=bar </bar>
    </pig>
</pets>
```

Now, you only care about all `pets` having any child `bar` **that has an attribute `att` with value `baz`**. You can use the following xpath expression:

```
//pets/*[descendant::bar[@att='baz']]
```

Result

```
<lizard>
    <bar att="baz">lizard should be returned, because it has a child of bar</bar>
</lizard>
```

Comment: How about wanting all pets who's <bar> element has specific text()? Seems like I can't figure that one out...