# xpath keeps changing when a new entry is added to table

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select the checkbox against a table entry. But whenever there is a new entry in the table the xpath keeps changing(tr either increments or decrements). Attached is the source and xpath as i am not able to enter it. Could you please let me know how to select the entry

```
xpath = //*[@id='main']/form/fieldset[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]
```

Source :

```
<tr>
<td style="height: 20px">
<input type="checkbox" value="65" name="SelectedServersIds"/>
</td>
<td title="10.78.59.224 / 10.78.59.224">10.78.59.224 / 10.78.59.224</td>
<td title="N/A">N/A</td>
<td title="Linux SuSE EL Server 10 x64">Linux SuSE EL Server 10 x64</td>
<td title="Local DB">Local DB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 20px">
<input type="checkbox" value="73" name="SelectedServersIds"/>
</td>
<td title="10.78.59.24 / 10.78.59.24">10.78.59.24 / 10.78.59.24</td>
<td title="N/A">N/A</td>
<td title="Win 2008 Server x64">Win 2008 Server x64</td>
<td title="Local DB">Local DB</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105613/can-xpath-return-only-nodes-that-have-a-child-of-x to write a selector that has a specific child, and then you can select the <input> element from there.

Comment: How did you generate that XPath?

Comment: Hi Arran,I generated the xpath from firepath

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. Only change the text(Linux SuSE EL Server 10 x64) for a particular row.

```
//tr[td[text() = 'Linux SuSE EL Server 10 x64']]/descendant::input[@type = 'checkbox']
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you have looks to be too specific, whenever the source html changes there is a high chance that your xpath will break. You could use the following to hopefully avoid this problem:

```
xpath = descendant::input[contains(@name, 'SelectedServersIds')]
```

You can change the **tag:** '*input*', **attribute:** '*@name*' and **attribute value:** '*SelectedServersIds*' accordingly. Hope this helps.