# Only parse xml file if a certain element exists under a given parent element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
//Get and translate interface configs
var interfaces = CurrentXML
                 .Descendants("interface-list")
                 .Elements("interface")
                 .Select(i => new { NAMEIF = i.Element("name").Value ,
                                    DESC   = i.Element("description").Value ,
                                    NOSHUT = i.Element("if-item-list")
                                              .Element("item")
                                              .Element("physical-if")
                                              .Element("enabled")
                                              .Value
                                  }
                   ) ;

//Build ASA Configuration and display to user.
ASAconfig.Append( "<br />" + deviceconf.HOSTNAME.ToString() ) ;

foreach ( var el in interfaces )
{
  ASAconfig.Append(
    string.Format("<br />nameif {0}<br /> description {1}<br /> {2}" ,
      el.NAMEIF != null ? el.NAMEIF.ToString() : string.Empty ,
      el.DESC   != null ? el.DESC.ToString()   : string.Empty ,
      el.NOSHUT.ToString() == "1" ? "no shut"  : string.Empty
      )
    ) ;
}
```

I'm sorry if this was not formatted correctly, this is my first post.

I am creating a website with ASP.NET and C# to parse an XML file and translate certain element values and append to an arbitrary string. The problem I'm having is that there are "interface" elements within the XML file which do not contain an "enabled" descendant (would be element of "physical-if" that also does not exist for virtual interfaces).

I don't want to perform the selections from the XML file if this descendant does not exist, and as you can see I've played with a "where" clause but have struck out thus far. Part of an example XML file is pasted below showing the difference that I'm talking about. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

```
<interface>
  <name>SSL-VPN</name>
  <description>SSL VPN</description>
  <property>2</property>
  <if-item-list>
    <item>
      <item-type>5</item-type>
      <sslvpn>SSL-VPN</sslvpn>
    </item>
  </if-item-list>
</interface>
<interface>
  <name>DMZ</name>
  <description>DMZ</description>
  <property>0</property>
  <if-item-list>
    <item>
      <item-type>1</item-type>
      <physical-if>
        <if-num>2</if-num>
        <enabled>1</enabled>
        <if-property>3</if-property>
        <ip>10.21.2.1</ip>
        <netmask>255.255.0.0</netmask>
        <mtu>1500</mtu>
        <auto-negotiation>1</auto-negotiation>
        <link-speed>100</link-speed>
        <mac-address-enable>0</mac-address-enable>
        <mac-address />
        <full-duplex>1</full-duplex>
        <secondary-ip-list />
        <anti-spoof>2</anti-spoof>
        <anti-scan>0</anti-scan>
        <block-notification>0</block-notification>
        <dos-prevention>1</dos-prevention>
        <intra-inspection>0</intra-inspection>
        <dhcp-server>
          <server-type>0</server-type>
        </dhcp-server>
        <vpn-df-bit>0</vpn-df-bit>
        <qos>
          <max-link-bandwidth>0</max-link-bandwidth>
          <qos-marking>
            <marking-field>2</marking-field>
            <marking-method>
              <marking-type>0</marking-type>
            </marking-method>
            <priority-method>0</priority-method>
          </qos-marking>
        </qos>
        <static-mac-ip-binds>
          <restrict-traffic>0</restrict-traffic>
        </static-mac-ip-binds>
        <static-mac-acl>
          <enable>0</enable>
        </static-mac-acl>
      </physical-if>
    </item>
  </if-item-list>
...
```

Comment: So you just want elements which contain <if-item-list> element?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this Where:

```
.Elements("interface")
.Where(i => null != i.Descendants("enabled").FirstOrDefault())
.Select // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magical about Linq (outside of the fact that it's the current silver bullet *du jour*). It would seem to me that what you want to do would be easier and possibly clearer if you used XPath to select your element set.

- [Can XPath return only nodes that have a child of X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105613/can-xpath-return-only-nodes-that-have-a-child-of-x)
- [XPath find all elements with specific child node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881179/xpath-find-all-elements-with-specific-child-node)

Using XPath, it's as simple as:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument() ;
xmldoc.LoadXml(rawXml) ; // load your XML string here

XmlNodeList selectedNodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes( "/interface-list/interface[if-item-list/item/physical-if/enabled]" ) ;
```

It should be noted that an `XmlNodeList` is `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`, so to do any sort of Linq magick, you'll need to cast it like so:

```
selectedNodes
.Cast<XmlNode>()
.Select( ... )
;
```